# Check if two data attributes match, then add class to element

Tags: javascript, css

I'm attempting to try and create a scenario where when the user hovers over a thumbnail, it then finds the data-position attribute of the thumbnail and matches it with slides that has the same data-position and an active class gets added to the slide element.

My current attempt to solve this problem had problems reading the property of position for 'slides'.  I'm assuming this is a scope issue of some sort, but need some help in trying to get this solved.

```js
var sliderNav = document.getElementById('sliderNav');
var paraIns = new Parallax(sliderNav);
var thumbs = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbnail');
var thumbsArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(thumbs);
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slider__img');
var slidesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(slides);

for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slides[i].setAttribute('data-position', i);
} 

for (var i = 0; i < thumbs.length; i++) {
  thumbs[i].setAttribute('data-position', i);
  thumbs[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    console.log('Current thumbnail index is ' + this.dataset.position);
    if (slides.dataset.position == this.dataset.position) {
      slides.classList.add('active');
    } else {
      slides.classList.remove('active');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div id="sliderImages" class="slider__container">
    <div class="slider__img"></div>
    <div class="slider__img"></div>
    <div class="slider__img"></div>
    <div class="slider__img"></div>
    <div class="slider__img"></div>
    <div class="slider__img"></div>
    <div class="slider__img"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="sliderNav" class="slider__navigation" data-relative-input="true">
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.2">
    <div class="thumbnail__img"></div>  
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.4">
    <div class="thumbnail__img"></div>  
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.6">
    <div class="thumbnail__img"></div>  
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.8">
    <div class="thumbnail__img"></div>  
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.6">
    <div class="thumbnail__img"></div>  
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.4">
    <div class="thumbnail__img"></div>  
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.2">
    <div class="thumbnail__img"></div>  
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `slides.dataset` won't work, and neither will `slides.classList`. `slides` is a NodeList, not a single element.

Comment: Mark - Are you trying to create a solution where the user hovers on a thumb and it shows the larger image of the thumb? If so how are you loading the HTML ? Is it currently handwritten? You would want to link the two thumb ~ image perhaps with a class name or using a data- attribute.

Comment: @Bibberty no, the thumbnail and the image in the slider will be two separate images.  Thumbnails is a bit of a misleading explanation of what they are, they're an image of a product for the company, than the images that load on the slider are lifestyle images of that specific product the user is hovered over.

Comment: Ok, the solution below will work fine. But note how we link the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a model using event delegation and a data- atrribute to bind the thumb and the main image together.

```js
// This clears down any image showing already
const hideAll = () => document.querySelectorAll('#sliderImages div').forEach(d => d.classList.remove('active'));

// Show the actual image we want by adding a class
const showSlide = (id) => document.querySelector(`#sliderImages div[data-image-id="${id}"]`).classList.add('active');

// Event delegation model means we can add new thumbs and they will just work.
document.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
  if (e.target.matches('.thumbnail__img')) {
    hideAll();
    showSlide(e.target.dataset.imageId);
  }

});
```

```css
.slider__container {
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.slider__img {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div id="sliderImages" class="slider__container">
    <div class="slider__img" data-image-id="1">Big image 1</div>
    <div class="slider__img" data-image-id="2">Big image 2</div>
    <div class="slider__img" data-image-id="3">Big image 3</div>
    <div class="slider__img" data-image-id="4">Big image 4</div>
    <div class="slider__img" data-image-id="5">Big image 5</div>
    <div class="slider__img" data-image-id="6">Big image 6</div>
    <div class="slider__img" data-image-id="7">Big image 7</div>
  </div>
  <div id="sliderNav" class="slider__navigation" data-relative-input="true">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.2">
      <div class="thumbnail__img" data-image-id="1">Thumb 1</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.4">
      <div class="thumbnail__img" data-image-id="2">Thumb 2</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.6">
      <div class="thumbnail__img" data-image-id="3">Thumb 3</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.8">
      <div class="thumbnail__img" data-image-id="4">Thumb 4</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.6">
      <div class="thumbnail__img" data-image-id="5">Thumb 5</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.4">
      <div class="thumbnail__img" data-image-id="6">Thumb 6</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-depth="0.2">
      <div class="thumbnail__img" data-image-id="7">Thumb 7</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```